# Json parse url prestashop webservice

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services, prestashop

I ask you a question.

I need to parse a JSON coming from the Prestashop WebService.

At the moment I have saved all the JSON locally, in a file, I show it in a table and it works.

The code I'm using is this:

```
/// Read JSON
<script>
  $ ('# loan'). DataTable ({
       ajax: {
         url: 'products.json',
         dataSrc: 'products'
       },
       "columns": [
            {"data": "name"},
            {"data": "active"},
            {"data": "description"}
       ]
  });
</script>
```

My question is:
How can I directly use the url (https://www.mywebsite.com/shop/api/products/?ws_key=ws_key?&output_format=JSON&display=full) instead of using the above method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope one of these helps:

Using [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

```
$url = 'https://www.mywebsite.com/shop/api/products/?ws_key=ws_key?&output_format=JSON&display=full';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
```

Using AJAX

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET", 
    url: "https://www.mywebsite.com/shop/api/products/?ws_key=ws_key?&output_format=JSON&display=full", 
    success: function(data) {
            console.warn(data);
        }, 
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR.status);
        },
   dataType: "jsonp"
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried both solutions but unfortunately they don't work, the problem can be the access authorization to the prestashop web service?
example: https://www.mywesite.com/shop/api/products/?ws_key=TF7NBMR36K8YH3CC8W6RWXSPKK1GHTJB?&output_format=JSON&display=full

nothing is displayed.

Comment: So you haven't managed to get the json results you need to work with it?
In this case, the problem is not with the json parse, but with the integration of the PrestaShop webservice API?

Comment: yes, but with the integration of the PrestaShop webservice API

Comment: can anyone help me please this not working
`$('#presta').DataTable({ajax {type: "GET",headers:{ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'https://www.mysite.it'},url: "https://www.mysite.it/shop/products/ws_key=TH7NBMR87K8GG3NN8W6RWXPGVK1ABPJB?&output_format=JSON&display=full",
ajax: {dataSrc: 'products'},
success: function(data) {
console.warn(data);},
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
alert(jqXHR.status);},dataType: "json",dataSrc: 'products',"columns": [
{"data": "name"},{"data": "active"},{"data": "description"}]},​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​`